# How to install graphics in python any version?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, vpython

I am using Python 27 in windows and I needed to install some modules in it so using pip I installed matplotlib which worked fine but then when I tried installing graphics,it didn't work. I also googled where I found that Graphics can be installed for 3x version. I am using 2x version because I wanted to use Vpython as well which doesn't work for 3x version (atleast I found it is very difficult to use with Python 34). Then I tried using both the Python 27 and 34 and then tried installing modules in Python 34 but since matplotlib is already installed before,I am unable to install for Python 34.Also there is not module in Python 34. I just started using Python and I am having all these problems. Please anyone who could help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is meant by "Graphics", but as far as VPython is concerned, see the detailed instructions at vpython.org. The old Classic VPython did not work with Python 3. The new VPython 7 works in a Jupyter notebook with any version of Python and outside a Jupyter notebook (for example, using IDLE or Spyder) with Python 3.5.3 or greater.

Also, for VPython questions it's better to post to the VPython forum, where there are many more VPython users who will see your question than if you post to stackoverflow:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users

Comment: I think i have to start all again. I am confused wheather to use python ide or idle. Problems keep arising everytime i try with something.

Comment: I recommend that you post to the VPython forum 1) what version of Python you inslalled, 2) what platform (Linux/Mac/Windows), 3) how you launch VPython (IDLE, Spyder, Jupyter notebook), 4) a brief VPython program that fails, and 5) what error results.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
pip install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jminz/graphics.py/master/graphics-py_installer.tar.gz
```

This command from official readme: https://github.com/jminz/graphics.py

Answer (score 1):

open the terminal and enter the command:pip install graphics.py

Answer (score 0):

To install the graphics package

```
pip install graphics.py
```

https://pypi.org/project/graphics.py/